# JSON has no slashes when called from AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax, cookies

I'm try to get some JSON data that's stored in a cookie, when it's retrieved via a page load it has slashes (var_dump):

```
string(179) "[{\"name\":\"test 05\'\\\"\",\"var\":\"test::_(not selected)\",\"original_price\":\"20\",\"updated_price\":\"9.98\",\"sale_price\":\"9.98\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"item_id\":\"34\"}]"
```

But when it's retrieved via AJAX it doesn't (var_dump):

```
string(146) "[{"name":"test 05'\"","var":"test::_(not selected)","original_price":"20","updated_price":"9.98","sale_price":"9.98","quantity":2,"item_id":"34"}]"
```

Any ideas why?

Here's the PHP function that's called both by the page load and by a jQuery AJAX call:

```
function output_cart_html(){

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cart_items']) || empty($_COOKIE['cart_items'])) {

       $output = '<span class="cart_empty faded">BASKET - Empty</span>';
       return $output;

    } else {

       var_dump($_COOKIE['cart_items']);

    }

}
```

Here's how the cookie is set:

```
setcookie('cart_items', json_encode($this->cart_items, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), time()+60*60*24*30, '/');
```

Comment: use json_decode to get the content

Comment: @KOUROUMA Yes that is what I'm doing, but because it's inconstant I don't know whether to use 'stripslashes' or not. Using stripslashes on the second AJAX data returns NULL, I believe because there's quotes in the data. Do you know why the difference is occurring in the first place?

Comment: You're clearly encoding it twice. I'm not sure any of the code snippets you've shared illustrate that. I normally advocate for `var_dump()` as debug tool but in the case of JSON it isn't of any help, just `echo` it.